# Como Enviar dados de localStorage via AJAX para PHP e salva-los em um arquivo HTML

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Quero enviar os dados salvos no LocalStorage com PHP para um arquivo ou para um banco de dados não necessariamente precisa ser código PHP preciso de alguma solução para isso

```
<h2>Likes</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>
<button name="clique" class="btn btn-primary" id="like" type="button">
Likes <span class="badge" id="likeQt"> 0 </span>
</button>
<p id="date" style="display: none;">Data e horário do último like: <span id="dateLike" ></span></p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
 
    $().ready(function(){
 
    atualizarSpan();
    function dadosClick(){
    if(typeof(localStorage)){
     let likes= '';
       if(localStorage.likes){
                    
       likes=JSON.parse(localStorage.likes);
                   
       likes={numberLike:Number(likes.numberLike)+1,date:Date()};
                 
       localStorage.likes=JSON.stringify(likes);
       console.table(JSON.parse(localStorage.likes));
                 
       atualizarSpan();
       }else{
                    
       likes={numberLike:1,date:Date()};
                  
       localStorage.likes=JSON.stringify(likes);
                   
       console.table(JSON.parse(localStorage.likes));
                  
       atualizarSpan();
       }
       }else{
       alert('Navegador não suporta localStorage.');
       }
       }
         
       function atualizarSpan(){
            
       if(localStorage.likes){
       var likeQt=JSON.parse(localStorage.likes);
          
       $("#date").show("slow");
       $("#dateLike").html(likeQt.date);
           
       $("#likeQt").html(likeQt.numberLike);
       }
       }
        
       $("#like").click(function(){
            dadosClick();
       });

    });
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa, então, não sei se entendi muito bem a sua necessidade, mas para você enviar esses dados salvos no localStorage, ou qualquer outro dado, é bem simples utilizando `AJAX`.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST', // seu método pro backend
    data: { 
       dado: 'qualquer-dado',
       likes: localStorage.likes 
    }, // seus dados a serem passados, que podem ser o que você quiser
    url: 'seu-backend.php',
    success: () => alert('Dados enviados com sucesso!'), // só entra aqui se a requisição tiver sucesso
    error: () => alert('Algum erro ocorreu') // entra aqui se tiver algum erro, url errada etc
})
```

Assim você consegue enviar os dados para o seu backend ai e fazer sua inserção no banco de dados, etc....

Também há outras formas se você não quiser utilizar ajax, pode botar os dados do localStorage dentro de um form e dar submit, as possibilidades são diversas.

Espero ter ajudado!!

Comment: Obrigado! Mas Como faço para colocar dentro do form e dar submit?

Comment: Digamos que você tem um form, e nele um input esperando receber esse valor, é simples: `$('seu-input').value( localStorage.likes )`, e pronto, ta no seu form. Se você quiser isso de forma automática sem a necessidade do user clicar em submit, pode dar um `$(seu-form).submit()`, mas ai não tem nem pq não usar ajax na minha opiniao

Comment: como faço para receber os dados lá do código acima?

Comment: Quais dados? Se forem os do `localstorage`, como mencionei acima, é só uma questão de relacionar chave e valor e ler eles no seu backend

Comment: Sim são os do localstorage queria saber como poderia pegar eles no backend

Comment: Mano se você fizer o que eu falei na resposta, você vai estar fazendo um `POST/GET` na url que passou como parametro, e na respectiva page no backend é do mesmo jeito: `$_POST['likes']` etc.. daí você consegue obter eles e fazer oq deseja